# why is my score not increasing when a correct answer is chosen?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call the increaseScore() function to increase the score by 1 each time the correct answer "A" is chosen. Right now it increases by 1 when you hit the start button, but that is the only time it changes. Nothing else happens when the correct or incorrect answer is chosen. Im not sure if the increaseScore() function is not written correctly or if its just in the wrong place. So lost

```
const startButton = document.getElementById('startBtn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('nextBtn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('questionContainer')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answerButtons')

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentQuestionIndex++
    setNextQuestion()
    
})


function startGame() {
    console.log('Started')
    startButton.classList.add('hide')
    shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
    currentQuestionIndex = 0
    questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
    setNextQuestion()
    
}

function setNextQuestion() {
    resetState()
    showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
   
}

function showQuestion(question) {
    questionElement.innerText = question.question
    question.answers.forEach(answer => {
        const button = document.createElement('button')
        button.innerText = answer.text
        button.classList.add('btn')
        if (answer.correct) { 
            button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
            increaseScore()
        }
        button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
        answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    })
}

function resetState() {
    clearStatusClass(document.body)
    nextButton.classList.add('hide')
    while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
        answerButtonsElement.removeChild
        (answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
        
    }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
    const selectedButton = e.target
    const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
    setStatusClass(document.body,correct)
    Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
        setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
       
    })
    if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1){
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
    } else {
        startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
        startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
    if (correct) {
        element.classList.add('correct')
        
    }else {
        element.classList.add('wrong')
    }
}
function increaseScore(){
    console.log('score increase', score)
    return displayScore.innerHTML = score + 1
    
}



function clearStatusClass(element) {
    element.classList.remove('correct')
    element.classList.remove('wrong')
}

const questions = [
    {
        question: "What is question #1",
        answers: [
            { text: 'A', correct: true},
            { text: 'B', correct: false},
            { text: 'C', correct: false},
            { text: 'D', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What is question #2",
        answers: [
            { text: 'A', correct: true},
            { text: 'B', correct: false},
            { text: 'C', correct: false},
            { text: 'D', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What is question #3",
        answers: [
            { text: 'A', correct: true},
            { text: 'B', correct: false},
            { text: 'C', correct: false},
            { text: 'D', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What is question #4",
        answers: [
            { text: 'A', correct: true},
            { text: 'B', correct: false},
            { text: 'C', correct: false},
            { text: 'D', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What is question #5",
        answers: [
            { text: 'A', correct: true},
            { text: 'B', correct: false},
            { text: 'C', correct: false},
            { text: 'D', correct: false}
        ]
    }

]
var score = 0;
var displayScore = document.querySelector('.score')
displayScore.innerHTML = score
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you need to increment the value of score rather than just setting displayScore.innerHTML = score + 1. Consider

```
function increaseScore(){
  score = score + 1
  displayScore.innerHTML = score
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting it to increase after each click, correct and wrong. I cannot figure out how to get it to only increase on the correct.

Comment: In the showQuestion function, can you add a console.log to print the value of answer.correct before the if statement?

Comment: I think you will find that whatever is in answer.correct is not 0 or False so it evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling increaseScore(), which returns the score, but you are not saving it anywhere.

you have

```
increaseScore()
```

should be:

```
score = increaseScore();
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting it to increase after each click, correct and wrong. I cannot figure out how to get it to only increase on the correct.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of detective work quickly reveals that the culprits is `displayScore.innerHTML = score + 1`

You are not progressing score, just displaying 0 + 1
if you want to progress score your code should be:

```
return displayScore.innerHTML = score++
```

Comment: I am now getting it to increase by one each time i click next. Do you know why it is not working for only the correct answers? It works for every answer

Comment: Hey @howyie, that's because on page change you are checking every button whether it is correct, so one of them is correct which causes it to increase the result. What you need to do is 1) in your select answer function set a global variable to `isCorrect = true` (if correct). 2) in your setNextQuestion `score = isCorrect?  score+1:score`. 3) The last thing you want to do after increasing the score is `isCorrect = false` to reset it.